# Closed-form for finding the number of paths on an nxm board

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let a board $B$ be of size $n \times m $ squares where $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n, m \ge 1$. Starting from the upper-left square, $B_{1,1}$, find the number of paths to the bottom-right square, $B_{n,m}$, by going right or down at any given square.

For example, let $B$ be $2\times 2$, then the total number of paths is two: $(B_{1,1}, B_{1,2}, B_{2,2}), (B_{1,1},B_{2,1},B_{2,2})$.

One can calculate the total number of paths for an $n\times m$ board by representing the board as a matrix where the top row are 1s and the left-most column are 1s, then the number of paths to get to $B_{n,m} = B_{n-1,m} + B_{n,m-1}$. Going further, the total paths can be expressed as the closed-form $\frac{(n-1+m-1)!}{(n-1)!(m-1)!}$.

When the problem is extended to allow movements of right, right-down, and down at any given square, the closed-form above breaks down. As an example for a board $B$ of size $2\times 2$, the total number of paths is three now: $(B_{1,1}, B_{1,2}, B_{2,2}), (B_{1,1}, B_{2,2}), (B_{1,1},B_{2,1},B_{2,2})$. One could still calculate the total paths doing the matrix method above, but I'm interested in whether a closed-form exist?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number . Using keyword "Delannoy" brings interesting tracks on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t$ be the number of diagonal moves. Then there are $n-1-t$ horizontal moves and $m-1-t$ vertical moves, for a total of $\binom{n+m-2-t}{t,n-1-t,m-1-t}$ paths (this is a multinomial coefficient). Therefore the total number of paths is
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{\min(n,m)-1} \binom{n+m-2-t}{t,n-1-t,m-1-t}.
$$
I'm not sure this can be simplified any further.